# C++ Disjoint Set Implementation with Doubly Linked Lists

Tags: c++, implementation, doubly-linked-list, disjoint-sets

Can someone help me find/make/point me in the right direction of a disjoint set implementation using Doubly Linked Lists? I have some supplemental code and I've already started editing it, I was wondering if someone could help me fill the rest in or at least give me some pointers on how to do so.

## DisjointSet.h

```
#pragma once

#include "TemplateDoublyLinkedList.h"
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Disjoint Set
template <typename T>
class DisjointSet {
private:
    vector<DListNode<T>*> nodeLocator;
public:
    ~DisjointSet();
    DisjointSet(int n) { nodeLocator.resize(n); }
    vector<DListNode<T>*> getNodeLocator() const { return nodeLocator; }
    DListNode<T>* MakeSet(int key, T node);
    DListNode<T>* Union(DListNode<T> nodeI, DListNode<T> nodeJ);
    DListNode<T>* FindSet(DListNode<T> node);
    DListNode<T>* FindSet(int nodeKey);
};

template <typename T>
DListNode<T>* DisjointSet<T>::MakeSet(int key, T node)
{
    DListNode<T> *temp = new DListNode(key, node);
    nodeLocator.insert(nodeLocator.begin() + key - 1, temp);
    return temp;
}


template <typename T>
DListNode<T>* DisjointSet<T>::Union(DListNode<T> nodeI, DListNode<T> nodeJ){
    if (nodeI.getListSize() >= nodeJ.getListSize())
    {
        nodeI.getTrailer()->setNext(nodeJ.getRepresentative());
        nodeJ.getRepresentative()->setPrevious(nodeI.getTrailer());
        nodeI.getRepresentative()->setTrailer(nodeJ.getTrailer());
        nodeJ.getRepresentative()->setTrailer(NULL);
        nodeJ.getRepresentative()->setRepresentative(nodeI.getRepresentative());
        nodeI.setListSize(nodeI.getListSize()+nodeJ.getListSize());

        return nodeI.getRepresentative();
    }
    else if (nodeI.getListSize() < nodeJ.getListSize())
    {
        nodeJ.getTrailer()->setNext(nodeI.getRepresentative());
        nodeI.getRepresentative()->setPrevious(nodeJ.getTrailer());
        nodeJ.getRepresentative()->setTrailer(nodeI.getTrailer());
        nodeI.getRepresentative()->setTrailer(NULL);
        nodeI.getRepresentative()->setRepresentative(nodeJ.getRepresentative());
        nodeJ.setListSize(nodeI.getListSize() + nodeJ.getListSize());

        return nodeJ.getRepresentative();
    }
    return NULL;
}

template <typename T>
DListNode<T>* DisjointSet<T>::FindSet(DListNode<T> node){

}

template <typename T>
DListNode<T>* DisjointSet<T>::FindSet(int nodeKey){
    if (nodeLocator[nodeKey-1]) != NULL)
        return nodeLocator[nodeKey-1];
    else
        return nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
ostream& DisjointSet<T>::operator<<(ostream& out, const DisjointSet<T>& ds){

}
```

## TemplateDoublyLinkedList.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

// list node
template <typename T>
class DListNode {
private:
  friend class DisjointSet;
  int key, listSize;
  T obj;
  DListNode *prev, *next, *representative; 
  DListNode *trailer; //just the representative node has this pointer assigned
public:
  DListNode(int k, T e, DListNode *p = NULL, DListNode *n = NULL)
    : key(k), obj(e), prev(p), next(n) { listSize = 1; }
  T getElem() const { return obj; }
  T& getElemt() { return obj; }
  DListNode<T> * getNext() const { return next; }
  DListNode<T> * getPrev() const { return prev; }
  void setNext(DListNode* n) { this->next = n; }
  void setPrevious(DListNode* p) { this->prev = p; }
  DListNode<T>* insert_before(T d); // insert the int before this node
  // return a pointer to the inserted node
  DListNode<T>* insert_after(T d); // insert the int after this node
  // return a pointer to the inserted node
  void delete_before(); // delete the node before this node
  void delete_after(); // delete the node after this node
  int getKey() { return key; }
  DListNode<T>* getRepresentative() const { return representative; }
  DListNode<T>* getTrailer() const { return trailer; }
  void setRepresentative(DListNode* rep);
  void setTrailer(DListNode* trail);
  int getListSize() { return this->getRepresentative()->listSize; }
  void setListSize(int lSize) 
 { this->listSize = lSize; if(this->next != NULL) this->next->setListSize(lSize); }
};

template <typename T>
void DListNode<T>::setRepresentative(DListNode* rep) {
  this->representative = rep;
  if (this->next != NULL)
  {
      this->next->setRepresentative(rep);
  }
}

template <typename T>
void DListNode<T>::setTrailer(DListNode* trail) {
  this->representative = trail;
}

template <typename T>
DListNode<T>* DListNode<T>::insert_before(T d) {
  DListNode<T>* temp = new DListNode(d);  //temp pointer // 1 OPERATION

  if(prev!= NULL){   //if previous is not null // 2 OPERATION
    temp -> next = this;    //initialize next // 2 OPERATION
    temp -> prev = prev;   //initialize previous // 2 OPERATION
    prev -> next = temp;   // insert in the list  // 2 OPERATION
    prev = temp;          // 1 OPERATION
  }
  else{       //if null than do a simple insert
    temp -> next = this;  // 2 OPERATION
    prev = temp;   // 1 OPERATION
  }

  return temp; // 1 OPERATION
}

template <typename T>
DListNode<T>* DListNode<T>::insert_after(T d) {
  DListNode<T>* temp = new DListNode(d);   // 2 OPERATION
  if(next != NULL){   //if next is not null do this // 2 OPERATION
    temp -> next = next;      //initialize next and previous // 2 OPERATION
    temp -> prev = this;     // 2 OPERATION
    next -> prev = temp;   //make the connection to insert // 2 OPERATION
    next = temp; // 1 OPERATION
  }
  else{ //if null than do a simple insert
    temp -> prev = this;  // 2 OPERATION
    next = temp; // 1 OPERATION
  }

  return temp;  // 1 OPERATION
}

template <typename T>
void DListNode<T>::delete_before() {
  if(prev!= NULL){   //check if something is there  // 2 OPERATION
    DListNode<T>* temp = prev;         // 1 OPERATION
    temp -> prev-> next = temp-> next;    //change the interconnections  // 4 OPERATION
    temp -> next -> prev = temp -> prev; // 4 OPERATION
    delete temp;        //delete the element // 1 OPERATION
  }
  else{
    cout << ">Error: Nothing is there :(" << endl;
  }
}
template <typename T>
void DListNode<T>::delete_after() {
  if(next != NULL){ //check if something is there
    DListNode<T>* temp = next;  // 1 OPERATION
    next -> prev = this; //change the interconnections // 2 OPERATION
    next = next -> next; // 2 OPERATION
    delete temp;  //delete the element // 1 OPERATION
  }
  else{
    cout << ">Error: Nothing is there :(" << endl;
  }

}
```

Comment: Couldn't you simplify a lot of the code by using std::list and some standard algorithms from the STL?

Comment: I definitely could, but for the assignment my professor wants us to use the Doubly Linked List that we made in a previous lab

Comment: @CodeClown Code Review is not for assisting in adding new implementation. This code does not seem to work as intended yet.